# Validate fields and show the error (if any) at tab pressing or when switching to a new field instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-functional-component

Tech: ReactJS and TailwindCSS.
Currently, the email field is validated and error is shown as the user types. Code:

```
<div className='flex w-full flex-col space-y-2'>
        <label htmlFor='email' className='text-sm text-gray-600'>
          Email address
        </label>
        <input
          type='email'
          id='email'
          autoComplete='email'
          required
          className='peer relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 invalid:text-pink-600 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none  focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:invalid:border-pink-500 focus:invalid:ring-pink-500 sm:text-sm'
          value={email}
          onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <p className={`invisible mt-2 text-sm text-pink-600 ${email.length > 0 ? 'peer-invalid:visible' : ''}`}>
          Please provide a valid email address.
        </p>
</div>
```

[image: emailFieldValidation]

Can I show it at tab pressing or when switching to a new field instead? I tried using onBlur / onFocus at

```
<p className={`invisible mt-2 text-sm text-pink-600 ${onBlur ? 'peer-invalid:visible' : ''}`}>
```

But this didn't seem to work. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach an `onBlur` handler to the input, and use that to manipulate a state item which will indicate if the field has been "touched" or not. The way you used `onBlur` dosn't make sense as `onBlur` is a prop of `input` and it's a function, not a bool. You have to do the heavy lifting to get the bool that says "did they touch this field".

```
const [showEmailError, setShowEmailError] = useState(false)

// ...

<div className='flex w-full flex-col space-y-2'>
        <label htmlFor='email' className='text-sm text-gray-600'>
          Email address
        </label>
        <input
          type='email'
          id='email'
          autoComplete='email'
          required
          className='peer relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 invalid:text-pink-600 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none  focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:invalid:border-pink-500 focus:invalid:ring-pink-500 sm:text-sm'
          value={email}
          onChange={e => {
              setEmail(e.target.value)
              setShowEmailError(false)
          }}
          onBlur={e => setShowEmailError(true)}
        />
        <p className={`invisible mt-2 text-sm text-pink-600 ${email.length > 0 && showEmailError ? 'peer-invalid:visible' : ''}`}>
          Please provide a valid email address.
        </p>
</div>
```

Note that writing form logic like this can be very tiresome with lots of fields. I'd highly recommend you look into a popular form lib https://react-hook-form.com/ which covers all the edge cases and and already provides the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: It works now, but when you go back to the field and start editing, the error starts to show as the user types again. This is due to the true state of emailTouched. Any fix for this?

Comment: Just edited to add that in

Comment: wow, thanks. That works perfectly.
However, since it's a tsx file, it shows error TS6133: 'e' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: I replace e with _ , the error subsided. Why did this work tho?

Comment: Just take away the `e` entirely and do `() => setShowEmailError(true)` if you dont need it

Comment: even when there's no error message, there's a space for it, and that breaks the format a little. How can i remove it?

Comment: You should consider using `display` set to `none`. By the name of the class `peer-invalid:visible` it sounds like it uses the `visibility` property which will leave space for it like you say